# Ruby on Rails v5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estimada red, estoy empezando a desarrollar en Ruby on Rails y me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

[image: Mensaje de Error]

El controlador (controller) se creó de la siguiente forma:
`rails g controller Pages inicio`

El código del controlador es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo Application.html.erb tiene el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión de nodejs instalada es la v8.1.2

La versión de Rails es la v5.1.1

La versión de Ruby es v2.3.3

Archivo Gemfile

`source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end`
[image: Archivo Gemfile]

Desde ya, agradezco de antemano las ayudas para solucionar este problema

Imagen nuevoError
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu `Gemfile`?

Comment: @Gerry ya he publicado el archivo gemfile

Comment: He visto el [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial) que te recomiendan en el sitio SO en inglés y creo que es tu mejor opción.

Comment: @Gerry, he realizado los cambios propuestos, pero ahora me muestra otro error que se puede ver en la imagen nuevoError. Igualmente también  sigo buscando las soluciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema que al parecer es común en windows; para solucionarlo debes actualizar tu archivo `application.html.erb` cambiando estas líneas:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

por estas:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Este cambio me ha funcionado con rails 5.0; el único inconveniente es que deberás cambiar el código nuevamente cuando pases tu código a un servidor no windows.

Comment: Al parecer hay un inconveniente cuando se instala la gema bootstrap-sass porque lo eliminé y todo funciona bien por ahora.

Comment: si hice los comentarios que me sugeriste y funcionó OK

Comment: @grandtjs Bien, solo verifica que tu aplicación no se vea afectada en ningún lado, especialmente donde utilices javascript.